# Why does perl allow reading in real time from a process filehandle if I print $_?

Tags: perl, process, real-time, filehandle

I'm writing a perl program that captures the output of another program, and I noticed that in a `while <FILEHANDLE>` loop (so `$_` contains the line read), the following occurs:

```
open XIN, "-|", "test_xsr"; # not getting in real time! FIX
while (<XIN>) {
    print ".";
}
```

prints

```
....
```

**after the program finishes** while

```
open XIN, "-|", "test_xsr"; # not getting in real time! FIX
while (<XIN>) {
    print $_;
}
```

prints

```
1
2
3
done
```

**in real time *while* the program runs**. (While I'm testing, the program *always* produces that output.)

Why does this inconsistency occur?
Is it possible to process output in real time without `print`ing`$_`?

Comment: I'm sure there's got to be a canonical answer that says that, but I can't find it.

Comment: It is not about line-buffering the *input* filehandle. It's about the fact that lines you read from `XIN` have newlines at the end. *Shocking*, I know. So, when you print them, the output gets flushed. Whereas, if you just print dots, the output sits in the buffer until it's filled.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Thanks, you found the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, if STDOUT is connected to a terminal, STDOUT is only flushed when a newline is encountered or when the buffer is full. There's a newline causing the buffer to be flushed in your second snippet, but not in your first snippet.

Add the following after the `print` to force the output to be flushed:

```
STDOUT->flush();
```

Add the following to your program to always flush after writing to STDOUT:

```
STDOUT->autoflush();
```

(Older versions of Perl require `use IO::Handle qw( );` to use these.)